# Error in SSL wrapper while cloning with Mercurial

Tags: python, security, ssl, mercurial, openssl

I've recently started working with Bitbucket and mercurial.  I can work with git repositories just fine, but when I try to clone a mercurial one, it crashes in `/Users/foobar/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mercurial-3.4.2-py2.7-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg/mercurial/sslutil.py` on line 36, with the error:

> ValueError: can't clear options before OpenSSL 0.9.8m

I am running OpenSSL 1.0.2c.

As is apparent from the file path, I downloaded python (and mercurial) through Enthought Canopy

I searched around and I found someone with a similar problem: https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hgsubversion/issues/439/unknown-exception-in-dispatchpy-value.  His partial solution (commenting out the offending line) was enough to make my download work, but I confess I am out of my depth in trying to determine whether this will cause any security issues with me using Mercurial.  Are there any potential security issues with this?  Is there any additional information you'd need to begin to answer this?

The file I edited is below (search for "==========" to find the line I removed).

```
# sslutil.py - SSL handling for mercurial
#
# Copyright 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008 Matt Mackall <mpm@selenic.com>
# Copyright 2006, 2007 Alexis S. L. Carvalho <alexis@cecm.usp.br>
# Copyright 2006 Vadim Gelfer <vadim.gelfer@gmail.com>
#
# This software may be used and distributed according to the terms of the
# GNU General Public License version 2 or any later version.
import os, sys

from mercurial import util
from mercurial.i18n import _

_canloaddefaultcerts = False
try:
    # avoid using deprecated/broken FakeSocket in python 2.6
    import ssl
    CERT_REQUIRED = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
    try:
        ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext
        _canloaddefaultcerts = util.safehasattr(ssl_context,
                                                'load_default_certs')

        def ssl_wrap_socket(sock, keyfile, certfile, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE,
                            ca_certs=None, serverhostname=None):
            # Allow any version of SSL starting with TLSv1 and
            # up. Note that specifying TLSv1 here prohibits use of
            # newer standards (like TLSv1_2), so this is the right way
            # to do this. Note that in the future it'd be better to
            # support using ssl.create_default_context(), which sets
            # up a bunch of things in smart ways (strong ciphers,
            # protocol versions, etc) and is upgraded by Python
            # maintainers for us, but that breaks too many things to
            # do it in a hurry.
            sslcontext = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)

            # ================================================
            # LINE I REMOVED
            sslcontext.options &= ssl.OP_NO_SSLv2 & ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3
            # ================================================

            if certfile is not None:
                sslcontext.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile)
            sslcontext.verify_mode = cert_reqs
            if ca_certs is not None:
                sslcontext.load_verify_locations(cafile=ca_certs)
            elif _canloaddefaultcerts:
                sslcontext.load_default_certs()

            sslsocket = sslcontext.wrap_socket(sock,
                                               server_hostname=serverhostname)
            # check if wrap_socket failed silently because socket had been
            # closed
            # - see http://bugs.python.org/issue13721
            if not sslsocket.cipher():
                raise util.Abort(_('ssl connection failed'))
            return sslsocket
    except AttributeError:
        def ssl_wrap_socket(sock, keyfile, certfile, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE,
                            ca_certs=None, serverhostname=None):
            sslsocket = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, keyfile, certfile,
                                        cert_reqs=cert_reqs, ca_certs=ca_certs,
                                        ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
            # check if wrap_socket failed silently because socket had been
            # closed
            # - see http://bugs.python.org/issue13721
            if not sslsocket.cipher():
                raise util.Abort(_('ssl connection failed'))
            return sslsocket
except ImportError:
    CERT_REQUIRED = 2

    import socket, httplib

    def ssl_wrap_socket(sock, keyfile, certfile, cert_reqs=CERT_REQUIRED,
                        ca_certs=None, serverhostname=None):
        if not util.safehasattr(socket, 'ssl'):
            raise util.Abort(_('Python SSL support not found'))
        if ca_certs:
            raise util.Abort(_(
                'certificate checking requires Python 2.6'))

        ssl = socket.ssl(sock, keyfile, certfile)
        return httplib.FakeSocket(sock, ssl)

def _verifycert(cert, hostname):
    '''Verify that cert (in socket.getpeercert() format) matches hostname.
    CRLs is not handled.

    Returns error message if any problems are found and None on success.
    '''
    if not cert:
        return _('no certificate received')
    dnsname = hostname.lower()
    def matchdnsname(certname):
        return (certname == dnsname or
                '.' in dnsname and certname == '*.' + dnsname.split('.', 1)[1])

    san = cert.get('subjectAltName', [])
    if san:
        certnames = [value.lower() for key, value in san if key == 'DNS']
        for name in certnames:
            if matchdnsname(name):
                return None
        if certnames:
            return _('certificate is for %s') % ', '.join(certnames)

    # subject is only checked when subjectAltName is empty
    for s in cert.get('subject', []):
        key, value = s[0]
        if key == 'commonName':
            try:
                # 'subject' entries are unicode
                certname = value.lower().encode('ascii')
            except UnicodeEncodeError:
                return _('IDN in certificate not supported')
            if matchdnsname(certname):
                return None
            return _('certificate is for %s') % certname
    return _('no commonName or subjectAltName found in certificate')


# CERT_REQUIRED means fetch the cert from the server all the time AND
# validate it against the CA store provided in web.cacerts.
#
# We COMPLETELY ignore CERT_REQUIRED on Python <= 2.5, as it's totally
# busted on those versions.

def _plainapplepython():
    """return true if this seems to be a pure Apple Python that
    * is unfrozen and presumably has the whole mercurial module in the file
      system
    * presumably is an Apple Python that uses Apple OpenSSL which has patches
      for using system certificate store CAs in addition to the provided
      cacerts file
    """
    if sys.platform != 'darwin' or util.mainfrozen() or not sys.executable:
        return False
    exe = os.path.realpath(sys.executable).lower()
    return (exe.startswith('/usr/bin/python') or
            exe.startswith('/system/library/frameworks/python.framework/'))

def _defaultcacerts():
    """return path to CA certificates; None for system's store; ! to disable"""
    if _plainapplepython():
        dummycert = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'dummycert.pem')
        if os.path.exists(dummycert):
            return dummycert
    if _canloaddefaultcerts:
        return None
    return '!'

def sslkwargs(ui, host):
    kws = {}
    hostfingerprint = ui.config('hostfingerprints', host)
    if hostfingerprint:
        return kws
    cacerts = ui.config('web', 'cacerts')
    if cacerts == '!':
        pass
    elif cacerts:
        cacerts = util.expandpath(cacerts)
        if not os.path.exists(cacerts):
            raise util.Abort(_('could not find web.cacerts: %s') % cacerts)
    else:
        cacerts = _defaultcacerts()
        if cacerts and cacerts != '!':
            ui.debug('using %s to enable OS X system CA\n' % cacerts)
        ui.setconfig('web', 'cacerts', cacerts, 'defaultcacerts')
    if cacerts != '!':
        kws.update({'ca_certs': cacerts,
                    'cert_reqs': CERT_REQUIRED,
                    })
    return kws

class validator(object):
    def __init__(self, ui, host):
        self.ui = ui
        self.host = host

    def __call__(self, sock, strict=False):
        host = self.host
        cacerts = self.ui.config('web', 'cacerts')
        hostfingerprint = self.ui.config('hostfingerprints', host)
        if not getattr(sock, 'getpeercert', False): # python 2.5 ?
            if hostfingerprint:
                raise util.Abort(_("host fingerprint for %s can't be "
                                   "verified (Python too old)") % host)
            if strict:
                raise util.Abort(_("certificate for %s can't be verified "
                                   "(Python too old)") % host)
            if self.ui.configbool('ui', 'reportoldssl', True):
                self.ui.warn(_("warning: certificate for %s can't be verified "
                               "(Python too old)\n") % host)
            return

        if not sock.cipher(): # work around http://bugs.python.org/issue13721
            raise util.Abort(_('%s ssl connection error') % host)
        try:
            peercert = sock.getpeercert(True)
            peercert2 = sock.getpeercert()
        except AttributeError:
            raise util.Abort(_('%s ssl connection error') % host)

        if not peercert:
            raise util.Abort(_('%s certificate error: '
                               'no certificate received') % host)
        peerfingerprint = util.sha1(peercert).hexdigest()
        nicefingerprint = ":".join([peerfingerprint[x:x + 2]
            for x in xrange(0, len(peerfingerprint), 2)])
        if hostfingerprint:
            if peerfingerprint.lower() != \
                    hostfingerprint.replace(':', '').lower():
                raise util.Abort(_('certificate for %s has unexpected '
                                   'fingerprint %s') % (host, nicefingerprint),
                                 hint=_('check hostfingerprint configuration'))
            self.ui.debug('%s certificate matched fingerprint %s\n' %
                          (host, nicefingerprint))
        elif cacerts != '!':
            msg = _verifycert(peercert2, host)
            if msg:
                raise util.Abort(_('%s certificate error: %s') % (host, msg),
                                 hint=_('configure hostfingerprint %s or use '
                                        '--insecure to connect insecurely') %
                                      nicefingerprint)
            self.ui.debug('%s certificate successfully verified\n' % host)
        elif strict:
            raise util.Abort(_('%s certificate with fingerprint %s not '
                               'verified') % (host, nicefingerprint),
                             hint=_('check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts '
                                     'config setting'))
        else:
            self.ui.warn(_('warning: %s certificate with fingerprint %s not '
                           'verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts '
                           'config setting)\n') %
                         (host, nicefingerprint))
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> ValueError: can't clear options before OpenSSL 0.9.8m
> ```
>
> I am running OpenSSL 1.0.2c.

Just a guess, but it sounds like the script is using Apple's version of OpenSSL, which is 0.9.8 (and not OpenSSL 1.0.2 that you built things against).

To ensure you use your OpenSSL 1.0.2, use [`DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html). Its similar to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` on Linux.

The other option is to omit `shared` from the OpenSSL `Configure`, so that your gear can only perform static linking. Apple's linker always uses the `*.dylib` if available (even on iOS, where its not allowed), so you have to be careful with it.

Comment: The problem I had was that, although I'd installed Python and OpenSSL 1.0.2e via Homebrew, Homebrew doesn't overwrite existing symlinks in /usr/local/bin by default so I was actually using a different Python and OpenSSL. Running |brew reinstall python| output a message noting this, and noting how to overwrite the existing symlinks. That done this problem was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming OS X.

Try checking what python you're using:

`which python
/usr/local/bin/python`

Then see where that's pointing

```
ls -al /usr/local/bin/python

/usr/local/bin/python -> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

Make sure you're using `/System/Library/Frameworks` python, if not, delete the `/usr/local/bin/python` symlink and recreate it:

`ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python /usr/local/bin/python`

Answer (score 0):

The line commented out was one that disabled use of some older and weaker encryption protocols; commenting it out allows you to use those older protocols.  Possibly the server doesn't support the more recent protocols.  Unless you are worried about the NSA getting their hands on your code, this is probably not that big a deal.